# svm kernlab in R

Tags: r, kernel

I was wondering how can I find out the best value of **sigma** when I use ksvm
(my dataset has 21 categorical and numerical variables with 1400 observations)
here is my code:

```
rbf <- rbfdot(sigma = 0.05)
model <- ksvm(target~.,data = train,prob.model = TRUE,kernel = rbf)
p <- predict(model,test,type="probabilities")
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree that `kpar="automatic"` may help, but this only applies some unsupervised heuristics and does not necessarily optimize the parameter for classification accuracy. The only way to do the latter is to write a wrapper that applies grid search in conjunction with cross validation. If you not want to write that yourself, the mlr package (function `tuneParams()`) can do it for you. The e1071 package (which includes an interface to LIBSVM) also provides a `tune()` function that does the same kind of thing.

Cheers, UBod

Answer (score 0):

ksvm finds out the best sigma value for you.
i m working by writing

## training the svm vector

```
ksvm_model<- ksvm(x=train,y=y,scaled=TRUE,type="nu-svr",kernel="rbfdot", kpar="automatic", prob.model=TRUE,class.weights=NULL,cache=100,cross=5);
#summary(ksvm_model);
# train and test the model over the test data 
next_y<-predict(ksvm_model,test_mat,type="response");
```

the "kpar="automatic"" does that for you.

jus check this.